# javax.annotations split package using jaxrs-api and guava in Java 17

Tags: java, maven, guava, dependency-management, resteasy

I inherited a java project which won't build. I'm trying to migrate to java 17 and have encountered what I believe is called a "split package".

I have several dependencies that requires `org.jboss.resteasy:jaxrs-api`. I have several other dependencies that require `com.google.guava:guava`.

`jaxrs-api` and `guava` both define annotations in the `javax.annotations` namespace rather than their own(?). When compiling, Maven fails with, e.g., `[ERROR] module slf4j.api reads package javax.annotation from both jsr305 and jaxrs.api`

When I try and exclude `jaxrs-api` the build fails because of other contents of the artifact. When I try and exclude `jsr305` the build fails because a few dependencies appear to require the library in their module.info.

I understand the preferred way to do this appears to be to use `javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api` in your own code, but I don't see it helping with 3rd party depencies.

I'm unsure how to fix this. I'm not using either package directly by my dependencies do.

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using and what is your target runtime?

Comment: jaxrs-api is older, version 3.0.9.Final, while guava is pretty recent, 30.1.1.jre. It appears that the google team is refusing to modularize guava to keep it compatible with java 8, including depending on the jsr305 lib. Target is openjdk 17.

Comment: Making libraries compatible with JPMS is extremely difficult. It requires every dependency to be defined as a module. There is no JAX-RS API of 3.0.9.Final, so I assume you mean RESTEasy. This is a very old version of RESTEasy and may not even be Java 11+ compatible.

Answer (score 0):

While working with split packages in Java, you frequently run into issues like the one you are currently experiencing.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-artifact</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
      <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
      <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

We are removing the guava and jaxrs-api requirements from our project's reliance on "my-artifact".

Alternatives include using an alternative library that doesn't have this conflict, or updating your dependencies to more recent versions that have the problem fixed.

Comment: But don't these dependencies need to included somewhere? I can force my-artifact to skip the two libraries, but I am still dependent on their code. They have conflicting overlap, but they still have unique contents that are required, i.e., each is necessary but insufficient on its own.